# Tablesorter does not sanitize spaces when filtering, PHP syntax error?

Tags: php, html, tablesorter

**Context :**
When I use a PHP echo `<?= &var ?>` in HTML, it causes white space in my HTML element.
I have already tried to modify the file with another IDE to be sure that it is not an issue of indents but I have the same result. Same result on Chrome or Firefox...

**Problem :**
The filter of the plugin [tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) also filters the white spaces and that does not return me the expected result. **It works if I manually remove spaces**

**Question :**
Is this a PHP syntax error or something else?

---

**My PHP code :**

```
<td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs date">
    <?php if ($approval['STACODEM'] == '200'):?>
    <span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover focus" data-container="body" data-content="<?= $imgDuesDaysPopover ?>">
        <img src="<?= $imgDueDays ?>" alt="" name="imgDueDays"/>
    </span>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?= $dueDate ?>
</td>
```

**In the Chrome viewer :**

[image]

**The line with a date :**

[image]

**If I filter, no results found :**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of your html layout. You can inline your code to solve this.

```
<td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs date">Everything in here</td>
```

Or you can customize how the tablesorter orders your rows.

Easiest inlining would be by assigning the result of your `if` clause to a variable.

```
<?php 
$img = '';
if ($approval['STACODEM'] == '200') {
    $img = <<<IMG 
    <span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover focus" data-container="body" data-content="{$imgDuesDaysPopover}">
        <img src="{$imgDueDays}" alt="" name="imgDueDays"/>
    </span>
IMG;
}
?>
<td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs date"><?= $img.$dueDate ?></td>
```

PS: But be careful, your `$img` variable will also have spaces if you don't inline it. (Don't know if your tablesorter completely ignores the html.)

Comment: Adding more info: Tabs and newlines are understood by HTML and displayed as a single white space. Inlining means to remove the tabs and newlines between your HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Ozan Kurt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3263836/ozan-kurt), I have stored everything in a variable so the code remains readable.

```
<?php
    $html = '';
    if ($approval['STACODEM'] == '200') {
        $html .= '<span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover focus" data-container="body" data-content="' . $imgDuesDaysPopover . '">';
        $html .= '<img src="' . $imgDueDays . '" alt="" name="imgDueDays"/>';
        $html .= '</span>';
    }
    $html .= $dueDate;
?>
<td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs date"><?=$html?></td>
```

Comment: Perfect, concatenating strings is probably the best thing to do!